# Send char array to queue on ESP32 FreeRTOS Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, queue, stm32, freertos

I am a beginner making a program for ESP32 using Arduino IDE.
My code works with 2 tasks, each one running in one core simultaneously.
Task1 runnning on core 0 collects data from various GPIO (ADC, Digital and PWM) and generate 2 char arrays that i need to send to the queue.
Task2 running on core 1 receives CANBUS data from a MCP2515 IC (through SPI) and print this data to serial @1Mbps baud.
I need task2 also to receive the 2 char arrays sent to the queue by task1 and print them also in serial, so that task2 will print its own data and also the queue data in serial, without "colliding" data.
Task1 generates around 200 messages/sec.
Task2 generates around 1,500~2,000 messages/sec.
These messages are in CANBUS frame fashion, around 25 to 35 chars each. (Not int, but numbers, letters, comma...).
I've read the FreeRTOS documentation about queues, but given my lack of experience i have no idea how to deal in this case, because i am not queuing INT, but char arrays generated by task1.
Before i was working with semaphores but it turns out that there is loss of messages, as while one task is running and blocks the other, data from CANBUS should arrive and will be lost, and vice-versa.
Below is my entire code. If someone could give me some light, i appreciate.
Thanks!

```
#include <mcp2515.h>
#include "PWM.hpp"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <movingAvg.h>

movingAvg avgsensorV1(8);
movingAvg avgsensorV2(8);
movingAvg avgsensorV3(8);
movingAvg avgsensorV4(8);

//declare tasks
TaskHandle_t Task1;
TaskHandle_t Task2;

//setup of Arduino pins
int V1 = 35;
int V2 = 34;
int V3 = 36;
int V4 = 39;
int sensorD1 = 17;
int sensorD2 = 16;
int sensorD3 = 27;
PWM my_pwm(25);  //define PWM pin reading with interrupt
int pwm_out = 13;
int ADCoffset = 130;  //defines the offset on ADC readings due to AREF offset

//PWM generation properties
int freq = 500;
int ledChannel = 0;
int resolution = 12;

//preparation of MCP2515
struct can_frame canMsg;
int CAN_message_delay = 8;  //delay after sending each CAN message - use to reach the desired fps
MCP2515 mcp2515(5); //define CS pin for MCP2515 on pin 5


void setup() {

  //start average routines
  avgsensorV1.begin();
  avgsensorV2.begin();
  avgsensorV3.begin();
  avgsensorV4.begin();

  //create task1 for sensors data collection
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Sensors,"Task1",2048,NULL,1,&Task1,0);                  
  delay(500); 

  //create task2 for CANBUS data collection
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(CAN,"Task2",2048,NULL,1,&Task2,1);
  delay(500);

  Serial.begin(1000000);  //Initialize serial
  analogReadResolution(12); //define ADC resolution
  my_pwm.begin(true); // initialize PWM function

  //define GPIO modes
  pinMode(sensorD1, INPUT);
  pinMode(sensorD2, INPUT);
  pinMode(sensorD3, INPUT);
  pinMode(V1, INPUT);
  pinMode(V2, INPUT);
  pinMode(V3, INPUT);
  pinMode(V4, INPUT);
  pinMode(25, INPUT);

  //MCP2515 definitions
  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_16MHZ); //set CAN speed 500kbps and MCP2515 xtal 16MHz
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();

}

  // Task1 on core 0 - read analog/digital sensors values and send to queue

  void Sensors( void * pvParameters ){
    for(;;){

  //read 4 analog values and take averages
  int sensorV1 = (analogRead(V1) * (3300.0 / 4095.0) + ADCoffset);
  int vavgsensorV1 = avgsensorV1.reading(sensorV1);
  int sensorV2 = (analogRead(V2) * (3300.0 / 4095.0) + ADCoffset);
  int vavgsensorV2 = avgsensorV2.reading(sensorV2);
  int sensorV3 = (analogRead(V3) * (3300.0 / 4095.0) + ADCoffset);
  int vavgsensorV3 = avgsensorV3.reading(sensorV3);
  int sensorV4 = (analogRead(V4) * (3300.0 / 4095.0) + ADCoffset);
  int vavgsensorV4 = avgsensorV4.reading(sensorV4);
  
  //convert 16bit analog values into 2 bytes MSB & LSB
  byte sensorV1B = (vavgsensorV1 & 0x00FF);
  byte sensorV1A = ((vavgsensorV1 & 0xFF00) >>8);
  byte sensorV2B = (vavgsensorV2 & 0x00FF);
  byte sensorV2A = ((vavgsensorV2 & 0xFF00) >>8);
  byte sensorV3B = (vavgsensorV3 & 0x00FF);
  byte sensorV3A = ((vavgsensorV3 & 0xFF00) >>8);
  byte sensorV4B = (vavgsensorV4 & 0x00FF);
  byte sensorV4A = ((vavgsensorV4 & 0xFF00) >>8);

  //send task1 message 1 to queue
  char CAN1[31];
  sprintf(CAN1, "%d,1,8,%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", micros(), sensorV1A, sensorV1B, sensorV2A, sensorV2B, sensorV3A, sensorV3B, sensorV4A, sensorV4B);
  ???????????;

  //read 3 digital sensors values
  int vsensorD1 = digitalRead(sensorD1);
  int vsensorD2 = digitalRead(sensorD2);
  int vsensorD3 = digitalRead(sensorD3);

  //read PWM value
  uint16_t PWM_value = (my_pwm.getValue());

  //convert 16bit PWM value into 2 bytes MSB & LSB
  byte PWM_B = (PWM_value & 0x00FF);
  byte PWM_A = ((PWM_value & 0xFF00) >>8);

  //send task1 message 2 to queue
  char CAN2[25];
  sprintf(CAN2, "%d,2,5,%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", micros(), vsensorD1, vsensorD2, vsensorD3, PWM_A, PWM_B);
  ???????????;

  delay(CAN_message_delay);
  }
}

  // Task2 on core 1 - receive CANBUS data from MCP2515 and print to serial + receive messages from queue and print to serial too
  void CAN( void * pvParameters ){
    for(;;){

      if (mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg) == MCP2515::ERROR_OK) {
        Serial.print(micros());
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(canMsg.can_id, HEX); // print ID
        Serial.print(","); 
        Serial.print(canMsg.can_dlc, HEX); // print DLC
        Serial.print(",");
        for (int i = 0; i<canMsg.can_dlc; i++)  {  // print the data
          Serial.print(canMsg.data[i],HEX);
          } 
        Serial.println();       
      }
  }
}

  void loop() {
}
```

Comment: You can consider FreeRtos stream buffers instead of a queue.

Comment: @ddbug Thanks for the comment. In fact as i have only one specific task to send data to another specific task, it is indeed a good idea to use MessageBuffer instead of queue, being a "lighter" solution, so to speak. Now starts the struggle to implement it. :)

Comment: Pedro, the queues are intended for messages of fixed length (or maybe pointers to something else). Stream buffers are intended for variable sized data, yes they are lightweight. Or, just do a classic ring buffer, with read and write pointers. Send a single notification from producer to consumer whenever new data is added, then consumer will fetch whatever is available. Notifications are very lightweight.

Comment: @ddbug Ring buffer sounds good, indeed. I implemented MessageBuffer with task1(core0) sending 200 fps to task2 (core1), which is receiving the buffer and sending to serial together with its own reading of CANBUS frames coming from MCP2515 module at around 1,650 fps. Didn't work 100% because i found that serial is spitting all task1 frames (ok!) but it looses around 20% of CANBUS frames, probably because the time is not enough to make all these loops. The bottleneck now is really how to speedup the program so i don't have CANBUS frames dropping... RingBuffer may be the one, will test. Thanks!